# How to run an executable file through JRE by default?

Tags: java, default, default-programs, executable

I could do it with OpenJDK, but it didn't work for my purposes so I'm using Oracle's JRE 7. I can run the jar through the terminal with

`java -jar filename.jar`

and can also right click the file and click Open **With > Oracle Java 7 Runtime**, but I can't set the Java 7 Runtime by default in the Properties menu (probably because the runtime executable isn't located in `/usr/bin`).

Any quick command lines I can type to set it so I can just hit enter on the file and launch the .jar with Java 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar question, and I found the answer, it was a missing `.desktop` file for me, and I included a guide to manually creating one (although I'm hoping that somebody will show me a better way) anyway, here is how I did it.

1) Open Gedit from the Terminal with root privileges usind `gksu gedit`

2) Open a `.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications` and copy it into a new file.

3) Edit the name, comments, and image to your liking.

4) Change the command to `java -jar %u` DO NOT FORGET THE `%u`

5) Save

6) Right click `.jar` file in nautilus, select `properties>open with>show all applications`, and select the new entry, select either `add` or `set as default`.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Tweaks is a useful program that can manage this I think.  Install and run it, then go to Admins > File Type Manager, select Category 'All' then find 'Java archive'.  Edit that, and if it is not on the list, use the Add button, and select it, or use the 'Custom command' option at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I gone through Internet and I came across one article with complete steps to run jar file

http://mlartist.blogspot.in/2012/07/deployment-netbeans-project-in-linux.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.